# Scheme 'ttps' not registered

Tags: java, android

I was failed to connect the internet through Android app，but if I debug it，I get Exception called "Scheme 'ttps' not registered"，what's the trouble it has？
I have tried to get some tips but I failed and，it's “ttps” instead of "https".

Comment: So you are entering https but it loses the "h" somehow? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url is wrong written... YOu´ve got something like `ttps://whatever.com` instead of `https://whatever.com`